Swiper arrows from Swiper.js in Javascript not working on click
So I´m using the swiper.js library and all the mistakes on the console are fixed and my HTML and CSS are aligned correctly, the arrows are showing and i can customize them. But, as I click on them so the slide can swipe, it doesn´t do anything and its like they´re not even there.
function swiper() {
  const swiper = new swiper(".swiper", {
    // Optional parameters
    modules: [Navigation],
    spaceBetween: 5,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    loop: true,
    freeMode: true,
    loopAdicionalSlides: 5,
    speed: 500,
    cssMode: true,
    enabled: true,
    observer: true,
    observeParents: true,

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    },

    allowSlideNext: true,
    allowSlidePrev: true
  });

  const nextButton = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-next");
  const prevButton = document.querySelector(".swiper-button-prev");

  nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    swiper.slideNext();
  });

  prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    swiper.slidePrev();
  });
}

I already tried these codes:
cssMode: true,
enabled: true,
observer: true,
observeParents: true,

And also tried creating an onClick event but nothing happens

Try to remove click event that you add to your buttons, just let swiper handle this
